# How to passthrough AMD GPU to ProxMox guest headless with openCL

Tags: ubuntu, amd-graphics, proxmox

I have a Linux host (ProxMox) and I want to pass AMD GPUs (1x RX480 and 2x RX580) to the GPU for doing OpenCL work (Ethereum mining) in a Linux guest. I'm not a Linux expert, so I want to be able to use the VNC GUI Console to access the machine to configure things.

For some reason, in my guest Ubuntu 20 the AMD GPU drivers simply don't work with the graphics cards configured as PCIE.

If the amdgpu module is blacklisted then the virtual display works fine, but then the cards are not accessible for OpenCL. If I don't blacklist the module, xorg always fails to launch complaining about glamoregl. Even though I have uninstalled the `xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu` and `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` packages, and even though I have removed them from any screen configuration in xorg.conf, something in xorg is still being very greedy trying to force these GPUs to initialize a display. It hits the driver error and then the entire display fails to load.

How can I resolve this so I can use my virtualized display as primary and still pass through my GPUs for other work?

Answer (score 0):

It's an unfortunate design of xorg that it doesn't seem possible to block it from trying to initialize certain GPUs for display purposes.

By chance, I found that by setting `pcie = false` for these cards in ProxMox, xorg completely ignores these cards. This allows me to use VNC to connect to my virtualized display and have the GPUs available for OpenCL work.